# Bank Account Sub classes OOP

Tags: python-3.x, oop

B)The BankAccount class should then have two child classes, named SavingsAccount and NonTaxFilerAccount. The SavingsAccount class should have a ZakatDeduction( )function which deducts an amount of 2.5% of the current account balancewhen called. The NonTaxFilerAccount class should have the withdraw function from the parent class overwritten. Where a 2% withholding tax is deducted from the account every timea withdrawal is made.

i did the first part but not getting the second one it keeps giving me attribute error

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, init_bal):
        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        self.init_bal = init_bal
        self.account = init_bal


    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the amount into the account."""
        self.amount = amount
        self.account += amount


    def withdraw(self, amount):
       self.account -= amount

    def balance(self):
       print (self.account)
class SavingsAccount(BankAccount) : 
    def ZakatDeduction(self,amount):
       self.account=amount*0.25
       print(self.account)
class NonTaxFilerAccount(BankAccount):
    def withdraw(self, amount):
       self.account -= amount*(0.2)
       print(self.account)
x = BankAccount(700)
x.balance()
y=BankAccount
y.SavingsAccount(700)
z=BankAccount
z.withdraw(70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have several problems.  Basically your implementation of the BankAccount, SavingsAccount, and NonTaxFilerAccount classes are structurally correct.  However:

1. Since the instructions say to reduce the account balance by 2.5% every time the ZakatDeduction is called, you should update the method to remove the amount as follows:

```
    def ZakatDeduction(self):
        self.account -= self.account*0.025
        print(self.account)
```

2. Since the instructions say to  reduce the account balance by an additional 2% of the withdrawn amount when a NonTaxFiler makes a withdraw3al you should update the NonTaxFiler withdraw method as follows:

```
    def withdraw(self, amount):
       self.account -= amount*(1.02)
       print(self.account)
```

Employing these classes to create separate accounte with 700 balance should be as follows:

```
BA = BankAccount(700)     #Create a base account
SA = SavingAccount(700)   #Create a Savings Account
NTF = NonTaxFiler(700)    #Create a NonTaxFilerAccount
```

performing the following then yields:

```
BA.withdraw(25)
BA.balance()
675  

SA = SavingsAccount(700)
SA.ZakatDeduction()
682.5  

NTF = NonTaxFilerAccount(700)
NTF.withdraw(25)
674.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute error is correct, and in fact its message tells you the issue. Your classes are ok. The error is in the usage. You have:

```
y=BankAccount
y.SavingsAccount(700)
```

This means that the `y` variable now refers to the `BankAccount` **class**. The next line attempts to call `y.SavingsAccount`, and the `BankAccount` class does not have a method called `SavingsAccount`.

Did you perhaps mean:

```
y = SavingsAccount(700)
```

Note that python is whitespace specific. While technically valid, for readability, you should use the same level of indentation everywhere, but some of your methods are indented by 4, while others by 3